# The wrapper around my Nav bar isn't working

Tags: html, css

my wrapper isn't responding to my CSS whatsoever, I have no idea what the issue is.

If not is there a way I can do this better, I'm trying to get my navbar which is quite small to fit on my entire page(The top part having full width and minimum height), just like any regular header i'm not sure if a wrapper is the solution if not tell me how I can do it better?

Here's my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/standard2.css" />
</head>
<body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.php">About me</a></li>
                        <li><a href="portfolio.php">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>

                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
width:1500px;
height:800px;
right:0;
left:0;
margin:0 auto;
background-color: #333333;
}
nav
{
    padding:0;
}

nav li
{
    display:inline;
}

nav li a
{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: #333333;
    color:#ffffff;
    border-bottom:1px;
    border-bottom-color:#000000;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
}

nav li a:hover
{
    background-color:#9B1C26;
    padding-bottom:12px;
    border-bottom:2px;
    border-bottom-color:#000000;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    margin:-1px;
}
```

Comment: The key is the width of the `nav li a` elements, wrapper has nothing to do with it.

Comment: The problem though is that if I edit the width in nav li, it'll make the menu options themselves wider but what I want it to do is have a wrapper I think around it with the same bg color so all I have to do is center the menu after it being done so it'll look like a normal menu? Or am I wrong here?

Comment: I think I got it now, added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding these two changes does the trick:

```
nav {display: inline-block;}
#wrapper {text-align: center;}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/FRtZS/ 
(changed the wrapper width to 100% to have it fit the screen)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the wrapper to be the width of the page, why have it set to a px numerial?

Did you try

```
#wrapper{
width:100%;
height:800px;
position: absolute;
right:0;
left:0;
background-color: #333333;
}
```

You would also need

```
html, body {
width: 100%;
}
```

because each element the wrapper is in also needs to be at 100% width.

Comment: You wouldn't need `html,body { width:100% }`. Given that they are `block` level elements, they act as though they have a width of `100%`. It would be different if you were talking about the height. Then you would need `100%`. +1 Though. Pretty sure this is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add css:

```
nav ul{display:table;width:100%;}
nav ul li{display:table-cell;}
```

Comment: Thanks for that to by the way makes it look nicer :)